# How to pass plt object function of matplotlib to another method in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Say I have a figure which I am able to generate using `plt.show`. Now I wish to pass off this `plt` object to a generic function like this -

```
generate_figs(plt):
    frmt = ['jpg','png']
    for i in frmt:
        plt.savefig('name.{}'.format(i))

generate_figs(plt)
```

Can something like this be done?

Comment: What is a `plt` object? `plt` is usually the name given to the module `matplotlib.pyplot`. You can instead pass the figure object to your function

Comment: Yep. That is what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on how many figures you have. If it is only one figure you can simply keep the function (mostly) as it is as `plt.savefig` will save the current figure.

```
def generate_figs():
    frmt = ['jpg','png']
    for i in frmt:
        plt.savefig('name.{}'.format(i))
```

If you have multiple figures, then you can pass the specific figure object into the function and use `fig.savefig`

```
import matplotlob.pyplot as plt

def generate_figs(fig):
    frmt = ['jpg','png']
    for i in frmt:
        fig.savefig('name.{}'.format(i))

fig1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(some_data)

fig2 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(some_other_data)

generate_figs(fig1)

plt.show()
```

Note: you must save the figure before any call to `plt.show()`

Comment: This does not seem to work. It generates blank whitespace images.

Comment: You always need to save the figure _before_ you use `plt.show()`

Comment: Okay so it was due my own minor nuance. I was generating subplots to I had to take out the 'fig' object defined when initializing those subplots. Thanks anyway :D